# Mp3 player cannot run in c#

Tags: c#

I had created  mp3 player using Media Controller DLL. But when am running this ,my Program class showing error "Input string was not Correct format"
Here i describing my code

```
    private void PlayMusicFile()
    {
        if (FoundIt)
        {
            this.SetButtons(true);
            if (MyPlayer.bFileIsOpen)
            {
                MyPlayer.Close();
            }

            MyPlayer.Open(MusicFileName);

            if (MyPlayer.bFileIsOpen)
            {
                imgIndex = 0;
                MyPlayer.Play();
                Muted = false;
                DancePic.Visible = true;
                btnMute.Text = "Mute";
                this.tbPosition.Maximum = MyPlayer.Duration();
                this.lblDuration.Text = MyPlayer.TimeCalculation(MyPlayer.Duration());
                this.tbVolume.Maximum = 1000;
                this.tbVolume.Value = MyPlayer.Volume;
            }
        }
    }
```

I used another way also
  [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand, StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

But Both are not working
 mciSendString("open \"" + p3 + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                    mciSendString("play MediaFile", null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

Comment: What line of code is throwing the exception? And what is the value of `MusicFileName`?

Comment: In program class Application.Run(Form1)\

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions! What line of the code *you posted* is throwing the error. And what is the value of MusicFileName?